# jQuery/Javascript bind function to window/document without specifying an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, binding

Is there anyway to bind a function to the document/window without using events or setInterval/timeout ?

i mean i would like to bind function like :

```
$(document).bind(function(){
 //if element changed class remove element
});
```

maybe it's a stupid question but i would like to not use loops over element.

Comment: And when should that function be called if you don't specify an event?

Comment: You need to *tell* the function to be called on a specific event/moment. Browsers don't have mindreaders :p

Comment: damn i thought it was possible ... :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to "on DOM change" events, take a look at these answers:

- [firing event on DOM attribute change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561845/firing-event-on-dom-attribute-change/)
- [Is there any "on DOM change" event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470931/is-there-any-on-dom-change-event/)