# Is there a way to use JS or jQuery to manipulate a JavaScript form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am with affiliate programs that give you little forms to put on your website, but often times they're entirely composed of javascript (so, no HTML tags , ID's or classes are inside of them).

Comment: You should be able to listen for a dom change event and then start running your custom code. See this answer for some help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470931/is-there-any-on-dom-change-event

Comment: most likely the form is being loaded from somewhere else or something if there is no html...i have no ideas right now.

Comment: If they render a form to the page that is *not* inside of a 3rd party iframe, than it is no different than a form rendered in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

These probably pull in forms using AJAX. JS or JQuery cannot display page elements by themselves, for that they need HTML. What you can do is use the [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview) to find the IDs or classes in the form they load in, and then after the AJAX call edit the form from there.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a form then it has to ultimately draw elements into the DOM for the page to render.  There's always a way to get at those nodes if you really need to, but if they don't include IDs or names then you'll have to walk the tree and look for specific relationships based on what you see in the finished page.  It will definitely be a PITA, but it's doable.