# Call jquery function when <ul> content change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to call jQuery function when ul content is changed.

Below is my code

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $('.ProductList').live('change', function() {
          alert('content is changed now');
        });
    });
```

HTML

```
<ul class='ProductList List Clear'>
call jquery function when content change here.
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
      <li></li>
</ul>
```

Suggest me some idea so I can solve it.

I am try to call function based on content change because I work on bigcoomerce customization and big commerce not allow me to access ajax function because of the limited access so I need to call function like that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470931/is-there-any-on-dom-change-event

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/change/ `The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to <input> elements, <textarea> boxes and <select> elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus.` So `.change()` doesn't work on an unordered list... Also strange alert message?

Comment: The question is how your UL content change?

Comment: Why so much upvotes, this question has been answered thousand times before...

Comment: **<ul>** content change is based on ajax response @roasted

Comment: i think no need to negative mark over here]

Comment: So in success callback of your ajax request, call function or trigger custom event. This is BTW what is suggested in hundred other relative duplicate topics...

Comment: i am try to call function based on content change because i work on bigcoomerce customization and big commerce not allow me to access ajax function because of the limited access so i need to call fuction like that @roasted

Comment: @Jalpesh ha, ok, third party plugin don't allow you to override ajax request. I'd say use a global ajax method like .ajaxStop() and check there if UL content has changed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Test that: {this won't work if specific ajax request is set to global false}

```
! function () {
    var ulContent;
    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        var $ul = $('.ProductList');
        if(ulContent !== $ul.html()){
            ulContent = $ul.html();
            $ul.trigger('contentChanged');
        }
    });
}();

$('.ProductList').on('contentChanged',callback);
```

callback is the function you want to call when content of UL changed. You should just call it directly from ajaxStop handler but usually we use a custom event.

Or use that if you don't know what previous syntax means:

```
 $('.ProductList').on('contentChanged',function(){alert('UL content changed!!!');});
```

Comment: what does the ! before function() signify& who invokes the function?

Comment: @user1692342 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function  That can be usefull when you minify your code

Comment: Thanks for the link! Wasn't aware of it. How do I check if the specific ajax request is set to global false? Could you check out the problem I am facing in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30544027/triggering-event-on-change-of-element-in-unordered-list-in-an-iframe

Answer (score 11):

This is a bit late response but I share it for new devs facing same problem;

Some might suggest using [MutationEvents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationEvent) but beware as this is being deprecated!

```
$('.ProductList').on('DOMSubtreeModified', function(event) {
    // dos tuff
});
```

The recommended way is to use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) like explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596231/can-jquery-selectors-be-used-with-dom-mutation-observers) but then beware that it is not supported in old browsers like IE8!

Answer (score 3):

`<Ul>` don't have change event, since user cannot change it, but if you update it's content with javascript you can call any function you have in your code after changing it

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).on('DOMSubtreeModified', function (e) {
     if ($(e.target).hasClass("select2-choices")) {
          console.log("cambio");
          alert("cambio");
     }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The ul element doesn't have onchange event like form elements.

I'm sure that the content of the li element is change by some function in your code.
So the better way is to emit an event in that function and listen for that event;

May be this would help: [Custom events in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14840483/1784412)

Answer (score -5):

You can use `setInterval(funcName, 1800)` Check List each 1/2 second if ProductList is changed

Example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e8vxxwjp/)

HTML

```
<ul class='ProductList List Clear'>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
      <li></li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
    function handleProductList(){
        if(jQuery('ul.ProductList > *').size() !=="undefined"){
        var ProductListNum = jQuery('ul.ProductList > *').size();
            console.log(ProductListNum);
        }
    }

    /* Check List each 1/2 second */
    setInterval("handleProductList();", 1800);
```

Comment: This is a dirty hack using setInterval() better stick with normal events.