# Triggering event on change of element in unordered list in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe, node-webkit

I am developing an app using node-webkit. I have an iframe which loads a webpage. The webpage has an unordered list and I would like to get a trigger if an element in the unordered list changes.

```
<iframe id="app" src="https://www.somewebsite.com/" nwdisable nwfaketop></iframe>
```

The unordered list does not have a class name and its only tag is `data-reactid="XYZ"`. However the first item in the unordered list always has a class name: `.abc`

From another SO question ([Call jquery function when <ul> content change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830813/call-jquery-function-when-ul-content-change)) , I found how to trigger a function if there is a change:

```
! function () {
    var ulContent;
    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        var $ul = $('.abc');
        if(ulContent !== $ul.html()){
            ulContent = $ul.html();
            $ul.trigger('contentChanged');
        }
    });
}();

$('.abc').on('contentChanged',function(){alert('UL content changed!!!');});
```

However I believe right now, the script is looking for the class `.abc` in the current page's source code rather than that of the iframe.

To extract the source code of the iframe I wrote:

```
innerBody = document.getElementById('app').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
```

What would be the way to make the ajax function look into the iframe's source code? Also what does the `!` signify in the ajax function?

Comment: It should work if iFrame on same domain: `$(document.getElementById('app').contentWindow.document.body).find('ul/*or any more specific selector*/');` But as jQuery is always called on parent document, and because i don't know how you update the UL inside iframe content (using ajax from iframe or from parent), this would need more testing i guess

Comment: the iFrame is of another website. Could Yahoo pipes help in that case?

Comment: Well, I don't know yahoo pipes but you could proxified it server side (maybe what is doing yahoo pipes, don't know). Now what makes change inside UL? An ajax request? I'm really not sure this logic using `$.ajaxStop()` method would work in your case. Maybe provide online link where this can be tested (optimally a jsFiddle replicating issue)

Comment: @A. Wolff possible to discuss over chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79203/js-discussion

Comment: you'd have better to provide all relevant code in question itself

Comment: @A.Wolff Not sure how to get this running on JSfiddle. However my external website is www.messenger.com and what I am trying to achieve is, check in the list of chats, if there is a change in the first message. If there is a change in the first element in the list, it indicates a new message has arrived and I should extract the text