# In a chrome content script check if a link appears on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

In a chrome content script I need to check if a link dynamically appears on a page, specifically a youtube link. I've already tried just looping the code, which is clearly not the right solution and the change event in jquery.

I'm guessing the best way is just an event in js that I haven't stumbled upon yet. If there is another way to check if the link has appeared I'd be glad to do that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [DOMSubtreeModified](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMSubtreeModified). Also look at this relevant post: [Is there any "on DOM change" event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470931/is-there-any-on-dom-change-event)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j5X48/):

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#links').append('<a href="">Link</a>');
}, 5000);

$(function () {
    // you can also use $.on below
    $('#links')[0].addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function (event) {
        $('#out').append('<b>EVENT</b>');
    });
});
```

Comment: DOMSubtreeModified is deprecated according to your link

Comment: Yep. It works in Chrome though and there doesn't seem to be a better alternative currently.

Comment: can you give an example I'm assuming i can't just do $(...).on('DOMSubtreeModified',func)

Comment: Sorry this was the link I meant to post about it being deprecated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659662/why-is-the-domsubtreemodified-event-deprecated-in-dom-level-3

Comment: Yep, you should be able to.

Comment: The problem is I want to add it to the whole document, `document` doesn't seem to be able to add event listener

Comment: I want to except your answer but it just doesn't seem to work in my case

Comment: Did you try `document.body.addEventListener`?