# How can my Chrome extension catch DOM object loaded after page load?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My extension finds and replaces text (by crawling the DOM looking for text nodes) using a JavaScript file loaded by "content_script". It works fine for text that is loaded with the page, but **some sites load more content at arbitrary times after the page has loaded**.

For example, an article loads comments via JavaScript only when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page.

Is there a way for my extension to pick up on those DOM changes and run on the text added that way?

Comment: You can check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470931/is-there-any-on-dom-change-event

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a jQuery DOM change listener?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener)